# MSBuild: $(WebPublishMethod) does not have a valid value

Tags: msbuild

Im trying to publish one of our web-projects with MSBuild. When I do it directly through VS 2017 it works fine but when I run MSBuild it fails.

MS Build command:

```
"C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild" MySolution.sln /p:DeployOnbuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=Properties/PublishProfiles/publish.pubxml
```

Results in the following error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4359,
>   4): PublishProfile(publish.pubxml) is set. But the $(WebPublishMethod)
>   does not have a valid value.  Current Value is "FileSystem".

My `publish.pubxml` file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<PropertyGroup>

    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
         <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
         <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
         <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
         <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
         <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
         <publishUrl>\\1.1.1.1\c$\Site\mysite.se</publishUrl>
         <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>

</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you try just specifying the file name for the publish profile? the `PublishProfile` parameter should fix up the default path unless the path is fully rooted (`C:\...`)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. I guess I can do that from the command line but not from my TeamCity build project. I also noticed that it works when I do the MSBuild from my Workstation but not from the build server so I suspect that there is a configuration error somewhere when it comes to MSBuild or the Visual Studio installation.

Comment: I meant using `/p:PublishProfile=publish` instead of the relative path in the build definition.

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this? I'm currently facing the same problem

Comment: In my case, the PublishProfile path was pointing to a non existing profile.

Comment: I know this is old but I just ran into this for a new repo I was building - basically moving from TFVC to azure git, was building locally fine and was banging my head about why I was getting this error when I added a PowerShell task to print out the contents of the pubxml file and it was not found when building! I then found that *.pubxml was in the .gitignore file I copied from another .git repo!!!